# Show current date in correct format in angular 2

Tags: mongodb, angular, typescript

I want to show current date in correct format 
Example is: 12/19/2016.
Now i am using Date.now(). But it show garbage value, I want to show only date.
I am also using pipes but pipes are not bind with database. Now i am using formcontrol, which get the current date using Date.now(). and later i must show this date in grid in html. 
My current code is.
Date.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

PurchaseOrderSchema = new Schema({
   PurchaseOrderNo: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    index: {
    unique: true
    }
   },
   Status:String,
   OrderDate: {
    type: Date,
    "default": Date.now()
  }

}


{ collection: 'PurchaseOrder' });

PurchaseOrderSchema.set('toObject', { getters: true });
PurchaseOrderSchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true });

PurchaseOrderSchema.virtual('locationname').get(function() {  
    return this.Locations[0].ParentId.LocationName;
});
PurchaseOrderSchema.virtual('Tempvendor').get(function() {  
    return this.Vendors[0].ParentId.VendorName;
});


PurchaseOrderSchema.statics.delete_by_name = function(name, cb_succ, cb_fail) {};
var PurchaseOrder = mongoose.model('PurchaseOrder', PurchaseOrderSchema);

module.exports = PurchaseOrder;

newpurchaseorder.ts file:
export class NewPurchaseOrderComponent implements OnInit {
  private PurchaseOrderNo = new FormControl("", Validators.required);  
private OrderDate = new FormControl("");
   this.OrderDate=Date.now();
 ngOnInit() {

    this.addClassForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            PurchaseOrderNo:this.PurchaseOrderNo,
            OrderDate: this.OrderDate,

            });
 }
}

newpurchageorder.html file:
<section class="page-form-ele page">
  <section class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>Purchase Order</div>
    <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="TabsDemoCtrl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="heading-container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6 margin-top-13">
                <h3 class="h3-color">New Purchase Order</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6" align="right">

                <form class="form-horizontal margin-bottom-0 margin-top-6" [formGroup]="addClassForm" (ngSubmit)="submitAdd()" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Date:</label>
                          <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="OrderDate"  id="orderdate" placeholder="Order Date..." formControlName="OrderDate" required readonly="true" >
                          </div>
  </div>                     

                        </div>
</div>
</form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

the server side will usually generate a json response with a ISO8601 date `2016-12-19` or a unix timestamp `1482140260`

When this gets sent over the wire to angular it's not a date. It's either a string or a number which needs converting to a javascript date.

This is because the json standard doesn't automatically deserialize dates.

You will need to do this manually.

```
this.http.get('/api/mydata')
  // Convert to json first
  .map(r => r.json())
  // Convert the items dates to javascript dates
  .map(items => {
    // Loop over the javascript array and convert the dates...
    items.forEach(i => {
      // before parse
      // i.date = '2016-12-19';
      i.date = new Date(i.date);
      // i.date now is a correct javascript Date object
    });
    return items;
  })
```

Comment: Thanx alot for superb answer :)

Comment: Could you please accept my answer as the correct one :)